# React + Typescript referencing select element using useRef and forwardRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, styled-components

I have a main component where I use `useRef` hook and a child component where I am using `forwardRef` hook and `Select` element. What I need is to get the value of `select` element. I can use `useState` hook over `onChange` event but it works when I change the value but does not work when I programmatically set, so I am using `useRef` hook to get the value. But the problem with it is, when I use `linkRef.current.value` it does not provide the latest value and instead gives old.

By programmatically I mean it's options depends on anther parent `select` element, so when it's parent option changes it's values update automatically. Suppose it's selected value was **9** and parent option change it's value would be changed to **1**. But when I try `linkRef.current.value` it gives **9** instead of new value **1**.

Here is a sample of my code:

> Main Component

```
const linkRef = useRef<HTMLSelectElement>(document.createElement('select'))

const func = () => {
    console.log(linkRef)
}

<Dropdown
  props={props}
  ref={linkRef}
/>
```

> Dropdown component

```
import React, {
  forwardRef,
  Ref,
  MutableRefObject
} from 'react'
const Dropdown = forwardRef(
  (
    props: Props,
    ref: Ref<HTMLSelectElement>
  ) => {
    const {value,options} = props
    return ( 
     <DropdownSelect 
      value={value}
      ref={ref}
      >
       {
        options.map((option, i) => ( 
         <option value={option}> 
           {option} 
         </option>
        ))
      } 
      </DropdownSelect>
    )
  }
)
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `but does not work when I programmatically set, so I am using useRef hook to get the value`  -   if that's the case, you should rather find out why setting the value does not change the `<select> ..` value, instead of trying to fix it with `useRef`.  When you use a `useState` variable for the `value` of a `<select>...` element, it WILL react to changes on the state variable (`setValue(..))`, so your problem is probably in the `<DropdownSelect>..` component.
Source:  https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag

Comment: @BennettDams `select` values do change and by programmatically I mean it's options depends on anther parent select element, so when  it's parent option changes it's values update automatically. Suppose it's selected value was `9` and parent option change it's value will be changed to `1`. But when I try `linkRef.current.value` it gives `9` instead of new value `1`. Sorry if I wasn't clear at first.

Comment: and @BennettDams in above case I tried using `useState` but  `onChange` event was never fired. It worked when I had tried using mouse.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bunch of things I would change here.  First of all @BennettDams is right in commenting that using refs really isn't the best way to go about this.  In fact, you're probably seeing this warning telling you not to do this.

> Warning: Failed prop type: You provided a `value` prop to a form field
> without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If
> the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either
> `onChange` or `readOnly`.

When forwarding a ref, you need to pass the ref either directly to a DOM element or to a component which forwards the ref.  So you can set `ref={ref}` on `select`, but I'm not sure about `DropdownSelect`.

It looks like your options are just plain strings?  React will like it better if you can use a unique key for each option.  Having your options as objects also allows you to select any type and not just strings.  Something like this:

```
interface Option<T> {
  key: string;
  value: T;
  label: string;
}
```

But I don't want to make this too complicated, so let's stick with the strings for now.  What you want is something like this:

```
interface DropdownProps {
  value: string;
  onChangeValue(value: string): void;
  options: string[];
}

const Dropdown = (props: DropdownProps) => {
  const { value, options, onChangeValue } = props;
  return (
    <select value={value} onChange={(e) => onChangeValue(e.target.value)}>
      {options.map((option) => (
        <option key={option} value={option}>
          {option}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
};
```